# C++ Overriding virtual function with different return type

Tags: c++

I was very surprised just now to see that this code (paraphrased) built.

```
class Foo
{
  protected:
     virtual bool CheckThis(int id);
}

class Bar : public Foo
{
  protected:
     virtual tErrorCode CheckThis(int id, char something);
};
```

I thought it was not possible to override a function with a different return type? Somehow this built. OS is vxworks.

Comment: What is `tErrorCode`? It's entirely possible that `std::is_same<bool, tErrorCode>::value == true`

Comment: `Bar::CheckThis` does not override `Foo::CheckThis`. The parameter list is not the same. They are simply two different methods that share a name.

Comment: Those are two different functions - the second one is not related to the first one.

Comment: Overloading and overriding are not the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, this method:

```
virtual tErrorCode CheckThis(int id, char something);
```

Does not override anything, because it has a different signature from this method:

```
virtual bool CheckThis(int id);
```

---

Note, that you might use the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier to ensure that the method in the derived class actually overrides the method of the base class.

So, this piece of code:

```
class Foo {
  protected:
     virtual bool CheckThis(int id);
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
  protected:
     virtual tErrorCode CheckThis(int id, char something) override;
};
```

Will not compile, but this one will:

```
class Foo {
  protected:
     virtual bool CheckThis(int id);
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
  protected:
     virtual bool CheckThis(int id) override;
};
```

Comment: So.. `Bar` hides the method (if that c# terminology works here). What happens when `Bar` calls an inherited method from `Foo` that calls `CheckThis`, which was expecting a bool?

Comment: @JDoe. From inside `Bar` you might either call `CheckThis(int, char)` directly or call `Foo::CheckThis(int)` because `CheckThis` in `Bar` hides `CheckThis` in `Foo`. In both cases appropriate method is called.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it was not possible to override a function with a different return type?

Yes, it is possible, but with some constraints.

In particular, you can't use any type you want, only a [covariant type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) can be used.

In addition, the argument types must be the same, otherwise it is not an override.

Example:

```
class type1 {};
class type2 : public type1 {};

class Foo {
   protected:
      virtual type1& CheckThis(int id);
}

class Bar : public Foo
{
   protected:

      // This is not an override, it is an overload.
      virtual type2& CheckThis(int id, char);

      // This is an override.
      virtual type2& CheckThis(int id);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, you should use the special `override` keyword. It allows the compiler to check if the base class has a method for the derived class to override.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0663233cc6969d5d)

```
class Foo 
{
  protected:
     virtual bool CheckThis(int id);
}

class Bar : public Foo
{
  protected:
     tErrorCode CheckThis(int id, char something) override; // error:  marked 'override', but does not override
};
```

Moreover, since you override a base class method, the `virtual` keyword is not required in the derived class.  The base method is `virtual`, so the overriding method is implicitly `virtual`.